# Adobe Air - restore a window that is maximized at start - restore size is larger?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

Basically what is happening is:

1. Window is closed when Maximized (of type AIRWindow.as which extends Window.as)
2. When reopened, this window is in Maximized state, and Air has no record of a restore window size at this point.
3. Click the Restore button - AIRWindow.restore() calls Window.nativeWindow.restore()
4. AIR resizes the window, but makes it basically the same size or slightly larger than Maximized state

We don't have access to NativeWindow file, or the restore() function, so I'm not sure how to affect the default resizing of the maximized window to a restored state?

Any ideas?

Note: NativeWindow is part of the airglobal.swc package

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to set the initial window size when you create it?

When I create classes derived from NativeWindow I set the x,y,width and height properties prior to calling activate(). This size is then used as the basis for restore operations if you subsequently maximize/minimize.

You could create the window at a specific size and then immediately maximize it on load if you initially want it maximized.

Comment: Hmm, that's an idea alright. I could have a default restore size, and set that just before maximizing it...

Comment: Its a workaround I might try, but still going to see if I can find a more definitive answer:-)